# How to read in mixed data from a .csv into Fortran as string, integer, and real

Tags: csv, fortran, fortran90

I have a subroutine that is to read in a CSV and eventually save it into a data array.  However, I am unable to get it to read in a string value properly.  I can get the real and integer values just fine, but the string comes in empty every time.  The data file always has the same exact format (F10.6,1x,I3,1x,A64) with an unknown number of rows.  My output is just the float value, followed by the integer, followed by white space.  What am I missing?

My data is in the format:

```
  1.100000,100,TEST STRING                                                     
  1.106667,100,TEST STRING                                                     
  1.106667, 48,TEST STRING                                                     
  1.106667, 14,TEST STRING
```

And my code is:

```
      SUBROUTINE GET_TRIP_DATA(FILENAME, NUMROWS)

      CHARACTER(len=256) :: FILENAME
      INTEGER NUMROWS, IOSTATUS, I
      REAL TIMEVAL
      INTEGER PERCENTVAL
      CHARACTER TEXTSTR

      NUMROWS = 0
      OPEN(5,FILE=FILENAME)
      DO
        READ(5, *, IOSTAT=IOSTATUS) DUMMYV
        IF(IOSTATUS .NE. 0) THEN
            EXIT
        ELSE
            NUMROWS = NUMROWS + 1
        ENDIF
      ENDDO

      WRITE(ITERM,*) 'NUMROWS IS: ', NUMROWS

      REWIND(5)

      DO I=1,NUMROWS
       READ(5, 901, IOSTAT=IOSTATUS) TIMEVAL, PERCENTVAL, TEXTSTR
       WRITE(ITERM,901) TIMEVAL, PERCENTVAL, TRIM(ADJUSTL(TEXTSTR))
      ENDDO

      CLOSE(5)

      RETURN
901   FORMAT (F10.6,1x,I3,1x,A64)      
      ENDSUBROUTINE
```

Comment: What is the output then? Can you show the exact form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character `TEXTSTR` is declared as a single character. So you read only one character and you then print it.

Also do not use unit numbers less than 10 to open your files. And especially do not use units 5 and 6. They are almost always preconnected for special purposes.

Comment: Well I feel dumb now.  I changed the declaration to `CHARACTER*64 TEXTSTR` and it works like a charm.  I also changed the unit to 99 to be safe.  Thank you very much!